When can we expect the Tor experience to be fixed?
Since about half a year ago anyone using Tor was unable to comment, flag, VTC, and more. This all is extremely frustrating because I as a Tor user have to edit my posts instead to respond to comments which is discouraged but on Tor that is my only option.
I do not understand why whatever mechanism is responsible for asking/answering/voting/editing is immune to the Cloudflare anti-bot filter or whatever but these other functions are not. Is it really that hard to just do to them whatever is being done for the functions that do work?
The post was tagged status-deferred which sort of means that they intend to fix the issue at some point in the unforeseeable future which is not very satisfying.
So now, 6 months later, what are the current prospects for getting the Tor experience fixed? Progress updates? Timeline?

I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing that part of it is due to lack of research, specifically reading what the description and extended info of the [tag:status-deferred] tag say.

Some would argue that SE isn't obliged to support Tor, same way it's not obliged to support old or non "main stream" browsers, guess that might explain downvotes. Personally I'm on the fence about it, and consider this to be just another nail in the coffin SE puts itself into by working against their users, i.e. the community.

Related: How do I get attention for a bug report or feature request that was deferred a long time ago?
